# How to check MySQL if a string matched with parts from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do a kind of blacklist so I store in my database

```
id|value
-----------
1|test.com
2|example@
3|@another.
...
```

Now I looking for the fastest way to check if a given string (an emailadress for example) matched with a part of the values from the DB.

For exmple
my@mail.com -> no result in db -> no spam
example@mail.com -> matched with ID2 -> spam
...

Is there a way to do it, insider, the MySQL statement?

For the moment I see only the way to load all values in an array an check this, but this way takes a lot of resources and it's really slow.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look into [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Comment: @Nick `LIKE` checks some value against another. What do you suggest - select all items from db and use `like` on each?

Comment: i only want to get the info if there is least one match, thats enough to know it's spam

Comment: I imagine this would result in an ever-growing list of `OR` clauses on that `WHERE` clause.  If this query is executed on every page request then it may eventually be worth looking into caching the blacklist table in memory and performing the check in code, refreshing the cache from time to time.

Comment: @u_mulder it's a blacklist so he has to check against every value... or am I missing your point?

Comment: yes, i have to check if there is any value from db as a part of the string (emailadress)

Answer (score 2):

Use Query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `value` LIKE '%emailadress%';
```

Comment: This is wrong - you need the other way around: `WHERE 'my@email.address' like concat('%',value,'%')`

Comment: @PrakashG thats not the way it should go -i have to check the emails if there is a match (also a part of the email) - if i do it in your way, test@test.com will iognore.

Comment: @StefB, What I gave you is a hint, No body here should give you direct answer required in your context, this need to be molded as per requirement.
And I'm sure that    LIKE will help you in this case.

Comment: if this is possible this is what i need SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LIKE '%emailadress%'; IN VALUE

Comment: @StefB try with my comment

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do the complete processing in MySQL only. 
Please note this will **not** scale on larger tables because no indexing can be used so keep that in mind.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM  (
  SELECT 
   'test' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci' AS word 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT  
  'example' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci' AS word

  # When you need more words
  # UNION AL   
  # SELECT 'another' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci' AS word
  #

) AS check_list
INNER JOIN
 blacklist
ON
 blacklist.`value` LIKE CONCAT('%', check_list.word ,'%')


# note COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci' might not even be needed to the used server 
# because it's depending on server config and used table charsets/collates
```

**Results**

```
| word    | id  | value    |
| ------- | --- | -------- |
| test    | 1   | test.com |
| example | 2   | example@ |
```

[live demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pHpcuZi525ZFLKF3Mn5xeP/2)

Or for a more optimal version which does scale on larger tables you have to use FULLTEXT indexing and `MATCH()`

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
 blacklist
WHERE
  MATCH (blacklist.`value`)
    AGAINST (
      (
        'test example'
      )
    IN BOOLEAN MODE
  )
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pHpcuZi525ZFLKF3Mn5xeP/3)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just a check with `LOCATE()` to see, if the string is inside a given email address provided as string?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    blacklist
WHERE
    LOCATE(value, 'my@mail.com');
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+


SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    blacklist
WHERE
    LOCATE(value, 'example@mail.com');   
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
```

See [DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n7CVq6rBAKWdQ8na1ZScyf/1).